# kafka + how it can be that begin offset is much higher then previous last offset

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

We are using kafka cluster with 3 kafka nodes with kafka version `0.10`

From the kafka logs we get a very strange message as the following

```
Beginning offset 1432 is after the ending offset 1298 for topic data.out.cars
```

note - we have 110 partition for this topic

How it can be that begin offset is `1432` while ending is much less as `1298`

What could be wrong in kafka configuration ?

Can we avoid this problem by tune some kafka parameters?

Comment: Whats retention you set? ...does data got truncated due to retention time pass..

Comment: we have retention hours and retention bytes , for retention hours we configured 48 hours fro retention bytes , we calculate this value according to disk size

Comment: do you think its realted to retention hours/bytes?

Comment: Yes probably by the time you consumed all records, messages got truncated due to retention policy and thats reason offset got jump to latest offset

Comment: so if you think this is the situation - how we can be sure about this? , I mean I to validate that data is purge and because this the offset isn’t correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suspect due to retention data got purged and offset got jumped to a new beginning. You can validate by checking the topic offset from-beginning position. If the message got truncated it will get started from a new position that will appear on-topic partition detail.

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper <zk_host>:2181 --topic test --from-beginning
```

If you are using a new API then use below

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server <broker_host>:6667 --topic test --from-beginnin
```

Comment: your answer seems to be logical , but do you think maybe there are other reason for my problem ? ( +! )